# How to correctly identify float values [0, 1] containing a dot, in DataFrame object dtype?

Tags: python, string, pandas, floating-point, contains

I have a dataframe like so, where my values are object dtype:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['A', '290', '0.1744175757', '1', '1.0000000000'], columns=['Value'])

df
Out[65]: 
          Value
0             A
1           290
2  0.1744175757
3             1
4  1.0000000000

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Value    5 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 120.0+ bytes
```

What I want to do is select only percentages, in this case values of 0.1744175757 and 1.0000000000, which just so happen in my data will all have a period/dot in them.  This is a key point - I need to be able to differentiate between a 1 integer value, and a 1.0000000000 percentage, as well as a 0 and 0.0000000000.

I've tried to look for the presence of the dot character, but this doesn't work, it returns true for every value, and I'm unclear why.

```
df[df['Value'].str.contains('.')]
Out[67]: 
          Value
0             A
1           290
2  0.1744175757
3             1
4  1.0000000000
```

I've also tried isdecimal(), but this isn't quite what I want:

```
df[df['Value'].str.isdecimal()]
Out[68]: 
  Value
1   290
3     1
```

The closest I've come up with a function:

```
def isPercent(x):

    if pd.isnull(x):
        return False

    try:
        x = float(x)
        return x % 1 != 0
    except:
        return False

df[df['Value'].apply(isPercent)]
Out[74]: 
          Value
2  0.1744175757
```

but this fails to correctly identify scenarios of 1.0000000000 (and 0.0000000000).

I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't str.contains('.') work in this context?  This seems like it's the easiest way since it will 100% of the time get me what I need in my data, but it returns True even if no '.' character is clearly in the value.
2. How might I correctly identify all values [0, 1] that have a dot character in the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.contains` performs a regex based search by default, and '.' will match any character by the regex engine. To disable it, use `regex=False`:

```
df[df['Value'].str.contains('.', regex=False)]

          Value
2  0.1744175757
4  1.0000000000
```

You can also escape it to treat it literally:

```
df[df['Value'].str.contains(r'\.')]

          Value
2  0.1744175757
4  1.0000000000
```

---

If you really want to pick up just float numbers, try using a regex that is a little more robust.

```
df[df['Value'].str.contains(r'\d+\.\d+')].astype(float)

      Value
2  0.174418
4  1.000000
```

Comment: Excuse me while I yell into a pillow (but thank you).